# Finding the distance from a mirror

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, word-problem

My friend sent me this problem, and my efforts to solve it have thus far been frustrated. I need some insight!

> Joe is 6 feet tall, and standing in front of a mirror that is at eye level, and is 3 feet tall. He is holding a model person 3 inches tall 1 foot in front of his eyes. If he perceives the model and his reflection appear to be the exactly same size, how far is he standing from the mirror?

I get a vague feeling that [the intercept theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem) can be used here, but am unsure how to model his model and reflection *appearing* equal mathematically.

A crude diagram:
[image]

**NOTE**
"eye level" is taken to mean the middle of the mirror is parallel to Joe's line of sight i.e. the diagram is NOT to scale.

Comment: Note that if you "reflect" the smaller yellow triangle through the mirror, it extends the blue lines to form a triangle. express the problem with respect to this triangle, and the math is straightforward.

Comment: @Sky The first diagram is more accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a simple ray diagram, the mirror bisects all rays from Joe's eye to Joe's image. Vertical displacement is not important.

By virtue of similar triangles:

Ratio of image heights = $ \dfrac{6^{'}}{3^{"}}=24 $

Distance to image = $ 1^{'} \cdot 24 =24 ^{'}$

Distance to image is one half, = $ 12^{'}.$